# Django JSONField: I cannot query using lookup

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, python-2.7

I have a Django model that has a postgreSQL JSONField, like this:

```py
class MyClass(models.Model):
    identifiers = JSONField(null=True, default=dict, blank=True)
```

If I create a field like this:

```py
MyClass.objects.create(
    identifiers={
        'my_identifier': '12345'
    }
)
```

and then query it like so:

```py
my_instance = MyClass.objects.first()
print my_instance.my_identifier   # prints '12345'
```

it's there. But if I query it using lookups, like this:

```py
my_identifier = MyClass.objects.get(identifiers__my_identifier='12345')
```

I get this error:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'my_identifier' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.
```

There are other parts of this codebase (it's Python 2, we're just reeeaaly behind on porting to py3) where this logic seems to work. I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: If I recall correctly that functionality was added in Django-2.0, but that requires Python-3.x

Comment: There are other part of this same codebase that seem do this successfully, I just can't see the difference between that code and my own.